# Screenshot with step by step click path

Tags: image-editor, screenshot

I has saw a screenshot with clicks path (step-by-step). I would like know which software (open-source or free) it´s recomended to do this.

My system operation is Windows.

Example. I clicked 2 x 3 =

Ex.: 
[image]

The screenshot software capture each click and draw the arrows automatically like step by step path.

Note: I wouldn't like using an software of edit image manually after captured image.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what OS it needs to run. On Windows, you can accomplish that with **[Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/):**

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>*Greenshot* (click image for larger variant)</sup>

*Greenshot* allows you to make screenshots from the entire desktop, a selected window, or an area, and edit it afterwards. You can insert arrows, text and more, can distort areas, crop, rotate etc.pp.

---

A similar tool for Linux would be **[Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/)** – which offers about the same feature palette, and can even be enhanced with a bunch of plugins:

[image: Shutter] [image: Shutter]
<sup>*Shutter* (source: [Shutter.org](http://shutter-project.org/); click image for larger variant)</sup>

Both variants would match your request – except for one thing: They won't draw the path automatically, you'd have to do that yourself. I'm not aware of any software that would do that fully automated.

Comment: Thanks Izzy, but I would like that the steps were marked automatically on each click without to use an software of edit image manually.

Comment: @Ernest I'm of course aware of that. But I have my doubts that such a thing exists – hence I wanted to at least give you something that comes close. So I fully understand you will not "accept" this answer (at least not right away, before giving the "real thing" a chance for a few more days/weeks). Consider it a "fallback solution" ;)

Comment: +1 for Greenshot.   I use it at work and at home.  Which reminds me that I meant to send them support in last quarter's batch.   (reminder: if you have the means, support your open source creators).